# MySQL - strange return for select clause

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, having

Why does the following clause does not return, for each userId, it's last connection date ?
I have 31 distinct userids in the table, each one with many dates...

```
select userid, date from connections group by userid having date = max(date)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you adding the `having` qualifier? If you want max date for each user's last connection try this:

```
select userid, max(date) from connections group by userid;
```